# Consume SOAP API in Java

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I have been searching everywhere on how to consume a SOAP API built in C# / ASP.NET in Java. I am currently using Spring / Spring Web for my projects and I wish to use a SOAP API with Spring-WS to no luck.

The envelopes are generated incorrectly and when I send a request it simply states 
"500 internal server error"

The namespaces at the top where it has SOAP-ENV:Envelope are incorrect and when using the WSDL in SoapUI the data is presented as soap:Envelope so I am not sure if this is an issue with how it is being marshalled into an XML string.

I am sending this:

```
    TestRequest test = WS_CLIENT_FACTORY.createTestRequest();
    test.setData(1);

    JAXBElement<TestRequest> req = WS_CLIENT_FACTORY.createTestRequest(test);

    getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(req);
```

This sends the request, but outputting the XML data that is actually being sent is incorrectly put together and the server doesn't seem to like it.

I am not sure if a C# / ASP SOAP API Server is handled differently to the way Java does things? If anyone can enlighten me on this please do help me!

Comment: SOAP is a xml communication protocol. Both C# and Java do handle it the same. The best advice is can give you is to validate the response you're expecting against the defined schema.

Comment: The language used to create the SOAP API should not make a difference on its consumption with Java. I would suggest you to first try soapUI and see how that behaves and then compare your request generated by your code against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to using the basic JAX-WS as part of Java and used the "wsimport" tool. It turns out when I did it before, it was missing off the SOAP Headers so you can actually generate the requests with the additional headers included with the following command.

```
wsimport -keep -Xnocompile -XadditionalHeaders -extension
```

Although this is not using Spring's implementation of consuming a SOAP API, it seems to work a lot better.